# Convert date/time to Ordinal number ONLY in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date, time, julian-date

I'm using

`c = clock;`

in MATLAB to get the current date and time. I want to convert the current date so that I can extract the day number in the year as an integer and store it as a single vector value. I.e day 1 up to day 365

I searched for a Julian Day function but the function `jd = juliandate()` requires at least 3 elements and formats it with the year and time. I can't seem to find a function that does this. How can I convert the date for just the date number as an integer?

i.e Feb 1st = 32 as an integer

Note: I'd still like to store the time from `clock` in a separate vector as hh:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conversion to `datenum`:

```
c = clock();
tsNow = datenum(c);
tsStart = datenum([c(1) 1 1 0 0 0]); % timestamp at the beginning of this year
daysInYear = tsNow - tsStart;
```

datenums are just what you want, the number of days since a given fixed timestamp (1-Jan-0000). Hence the difference yields the number of days in a year - including leap years etc.
Use `floor(daysInYear)` if you want the number of full days.

Answer (score 2):

How about subtracting the days upto january the 1st of same year?

```
>> x = clock
>> y = zeros(1,6);
>> y(1) = x(1);
>> y(2:3) = [1 1]
>> mjuliandate(x) - mjuliandate(y)
```

Edit: And if the hours, min or sec are not being ignored then using `mjuliandate` is better than `juliandate`, as it starts counting from midnight rather than noon.